# About the meaning of the phrase '''At one end of the continuum'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

''At one end of the continuum, some notions of computation are so loose that they encompass virtually everything''

I came across this sentence and tried to check the phrase on the internet but I could not find anything that will help me understand it. What does it mean? I think I have an intuitive and an approximate understanding of it, but not enough to put into words. Can you help me? Thank you.

For those who wants more context:

''Whether computationalism has empirical bite depends on how we construe the notion of computation. The more inclusive a notion of computation, the weaker the version of computationalism formulated in its terms. AT ONE END OF THE CONTINUUM, some notions of computation are so loose that they encompass virtually everything. For instance, if computation is construed as the production of outputs from inputs and if any state of a system qualifies as an input or output, then every process is a computation.''

Comment: Context would really help here. Could you provide a larger quote? Say a few sentences before and one after?

Comment: Sure. ''Whether computationalism has empirical bite depends
on how we construe the notion of computation. The more inclusive a
notion of computation, the weaker the version of computationalism
formulated in its terms.




AT ONE END OF THE CONTINUUM, some notions of computation are so
loose that they encompass virtually everything. For instance, if computation
is construed as the production of outputs from inputs and if any state of
a system qualifies as an input or output, then every process is a
computation.''

Comment: The (mostly theoretical) Turing machine could represent one end of such a continuum, with it being a simple computational device that can read, write, or move a pointer forward. At its core, the Turing machine is so basic (and its notion of computing so loose) that it can encompass many types of today's programs.

Comment: So there is a continuum from a handful of computations on one end (Turing machine) to a RISC (Reduced Instruction Set Computer) in the middle to quantum computation on the other end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**continuum**, *countable noun*
A continuum is a set of things on a scale, which have a particular characteristic to different degrees.

> *These various complaints are part of a continuum of ill-health.*

> *It is at one end of the cost continuum.*

<sup>https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/continuum</sup>

---

Your text is discussing the notion of *computation*. The set of ***things that define what may be considered a computation*** is the continuum being discussed here.

One end of the continuum defines computation very strictly: it's a computer performing an operation (maybe; just an example).

The other end of the continuum (as appears in your text) defines a computation very loosely: any operation that translates data in any manner (maybe; also just an example).

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[Continuum](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/continuum)

> a coherent whole characterized as a collection, sequence, or progression of values or elements varying by minute degrees

Many individuals fall in different places in a continuum. If we were discussing musical ability, I might place Dame Joan Sutherland at the one end of the continuum, and perhaps my tone-deaf fellow churchgoer at the other end. (It is not a technical term, but used in many walks of life.)

The author is presenting different approaches to computing, starting from the most simple (such as a [Turing machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine)). In the author's view, the Turing machine has very little "empircal bite" (meaning, it could implement plenty of algorithms, but would be mind-numbingly difficult to implement and even more so to verify. Imagine trying to find the prime factors of a large number using a Turing machine.)

RISC (Reduced Instruction Set Computers) would be somewhere in the middle of this scale. You can do a lot more, empircally, than you could do with a Turing Machine. You could write a prime factorization program in a few dozen lines using a modern compiler.

[Quantum computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computing) would represent the other end of this computing continuum. It has a huge "empirical bite" and is at the cutting edge of "computationalism." Prime factorization? That's one of the test cases for Quantum computing.